# Google API Calendar 403 InsufficientPermissions error

Tags: php, xampp, google-calendar-api

Earlier I sent some requests to get the calendar lists and it was working fine. But when I want to create a secondary calendar with another scope (Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR) it procs this 403 insufficientPermission error.

Here is the code

```
<?php
   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
   session_start();

   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setAuthConfig('client-secret.json');
   $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
   if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
         $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
         $service= new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
         $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
         $calendar->setSummary('CalendarioProper');
         $calendar->setTimeZone('Europe/Madrid');

         $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

         echo $createdCalendar->getId();

     } else {
         $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/oauth2callback.php';
         header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
     }
   ?>
```

And that's the error I get after executing the file

```
Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { 
"error": 
    { "errors": [ { 
            "domain": "global", 
            "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
            "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], 
      "code": 403, 
      "message": "Insufficient Permission" } }
```

P.D: I'm doing everything trough a localhost with XAMPP, maybe this has to do something with my problem?

Comment: thanks, my english is not the best sorry.